# Format of Numbers in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, format

Hi all I would like to format the numbers in Flex in order to show always three numbers. If the real number is 100 then show 100.00, 97.80 then show 097.80, 1.20 = 001.20. How can I do this?
I have the following code:

```
<ada:AdaNumericTextInput id="inInterestPercentage"
                                                 value="{selectedAgreementCampaign.interestPercentage}"
                                                 width="100%"
                                                 maxChars="24"
                                                 enabled="false"
                                                 enabled.STATE_EDITING="true"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom number formatter by extending the Formatter.

There is a good article on it here:
http://myxaab.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/custom-number-formatting-in-flex/
with source code.